# C# search by many parameters Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my table I have 4 columns: `BAZAR_TEXT`, `CATEGORY`, `COUNTY`, `PRICE` and I would like to search records by parameters from textboxes: search, category, county, priceFrom, priceUntil

```
var searchResult = db.bazar.Include(c => c.images).Where(da => da.BAZAR_TEXT.Contains(search) || search == null);

var categoryResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.CATEGORY == category || category == null);

var countyResult = categoryResult.Where(x => x.DISTRICT == county || county == null);

var priceFromResult = countyResult.Where(x => x.PRICE >= priceFrom);
var priceUntilResult = priceFromResult.Where(x => x.PRICE <= priceUntil);

return View(priceUntilResult.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
```

and need to return list to view.

If I search only by searchResults all is OK

```
var searchResult = db.bazar.Include(c => c.images).Where(da => da.BAZAR_TEXT.Contains(search) || search == null);
return View(searchResult.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
```

but If I add other results list is null.

Note: all parameters from textboxes can be null, but columns in table are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference between `null and string empty`. So if you search with empty textbox:

```
WebEntities db = new WebEntities();
            var searchResult = db.bazar.Include(c => c.images);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                searchResult = searchResult.Where(da => da.BAZAR_TEXT.Contains(search));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
            {
                searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.CATEGORY == category);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(county))
            {
                searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.DISTRICT == county);
            }

            if (priceFrom != null)
            {
                searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.PRICE >= priceFrom);
            }

            if (priceUntil != null)
            {
                searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.PRICE <= priceUntil);
            }


            return View(searchResult.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchResult = db.bazar.Include(c => c.images).AsQueryable();
if(search != null){
    searchResult = searchResult.Where(da => da.BAZAR_TEXT.Contains(search));
}

if(category != null){
    searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.CATEGORY == category);
}

if(county != null){
    searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.DISTRICT == county);
}

if(priceFrom != null){
    searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.PRICE  == priceFrom);
}

if(priceUntil != null){
    searchResult = searchResult.Where(x => x.PRICE  <= priceUntil);
}


return View(searchResult.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful for future visitors if you explain why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the order of condition evaluation
`.Where(x => x.CATEGORY == category || category == null)`

to

`.Where(x => category == null || x.CATEGORY == category )`